# "Chrome not reachable" using Xvfb in non headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

I am getting the following error:

```
  File "/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.122)
```

when I try to run the Selenium Chromedriver without `--headless` option and using `xvfb`.

It works perfectly in headless mode without the `xvfb`. I need `xvfb` because I need it not in headless mode in order to run browser extensions, which are not supported otherwise.

Why is this happening? Is there any way to achieve what I want at all?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the chrome and chromedriver versions are the same.